# Labeling sentences from different nested dictionaries

Tags: python, json, pandas, label

I created a function to extract sentences from a specific key in a nested file. Now I would like to **include in this function** a label each time it comes to a new dictionary.

Each time the the value HEADER appears marks the begining of a NEW story. So I would like to label the sentences that belong to the same story. And differentiate those that are different.

The data looks like the following:

```
sentences = [{'c': 'HEADER', 'a1': {'a': 'Opus dei, la vie en rose.', 'x': 'l'}},
      {'d': 'm', 'a1': {'a': 'Ipsum lorem, Suspendisse posuere.', 'x': '4'}},
      {'c': 'j', 'a1': {'a': 'Nulla elementum, augue fringilla tincidunt ullamcorper.'}},
      {'c':'h', 'b': 'p'},
      {'a1': {'a': 'Ut sollicitudin mauris sem, ut ultricies ante accumsan dictum.'}},
      {'c': 'HEADER', 'a1': {'a': 'NEW Opus dei, la vie en rose.', 'x': 'l'}},
      {'d': 'm', 'a1': {'a': 'NEW Ipsum lorem, Suspendisse posuere.', 'x': '4'}},
      {'c': 'j', 'a1': {'a': 'NEW Nulla elementum, augue fringilla tincidunt ullamcorper.'}},
      {'c':'h', 'b': 'p'},
      {'a1': {'a': 'NEW Ut sollicitudin mauris sem, ut ultricies ante accumsan dictum.'}}]
```

**The function**

```
def prhases_and_labels(data):
    a1 = [d for d in data if 'a1' in d]
    text = []
    for i in a1:
        text.append(i['a1']['a'])
    
    df = pd.DataFrame({'text': text})
    return df
```

[image]

**The result that I would like to obtain (with the labels in a new column)**
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what is the logic for the different labels. What do you mean by "a label each time it comes to a new dictionary"? You have a list of records (dictionaries), and each text comes from a different dictionary.  Why does the label only change when the text starts with 'NEW'? What is the rule which defines the label transition?

Comment: Hi,
The list has 2 greater dictionaries. Each dictionary contains a unique story. So I would like to label the sentences that belong to the same story. And differentiate those that are different.

Comment: The list given doesn’t contain only two dictionaries, it contains one dictionary per line.  The stories aren’t separated as you are saying. My question is how do you differentiate the lines of each story then? How do you know that the 3rd and previous lines belong to the 1st story, but the 4th and following lines belong to the 2nd story?

Comment: I see what you mean. I've inspected the original file. It is a huge json file. What specifies the beginning of a new story is the key containing HEADER as value. I added this to the eample above. Thank you for your persistence in trying to help.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad to help! Thanks for the clarification, now we have all the necessary information. See if my solution solves your problem and if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the records and increment the label every time the `c` value is `HEADER`.

```
sentences = [{'c': 'HEADER', 'a1': {'a': 'Opus dei, la vie en rose.', 'x': 'l'}},
      {'d': 'm', 'a1': {'a': 'Ipsum lorem, Suspendisse posuere.', 'x': '4'}},
      {'c': 'j', 'a1': {'a': 'Nulla elementum, augue fringilla tincidunt ullamcorper.'}},
      {'c':'h', 'b': 'p'},
      {'a1': {'a': 'Ut sollicitudin mauris sem, ut ultricies ante accumsan dictum.'}},
      {'c': 'HEADER', 'a1': {'a': 'NEW Opus dei, la vie en rose.', 'x': 'l'}},
      {'d': 'm', 'a1': {'a': 'NEW Ipsum lorem, Suspendisse posuere.', 'x': '4'}},
      {'c': 'j', 'a1': {'a': 'NEW Nulla elementum, augue fringilla tincidunt ullamcorper.'}},
      {'c':'h', 'b': 'p'},
      {'a1': {'a': 'NEW Ut sollicitudin mauris sem, ut ultricies ante accumsan dictum.'}}]


def prhases_and_labels(data):
    label = 0
    res = {'text':[], 'label': []}
    for record in data:
        if 'a1' in record:
            line = record['a1']['a']
            if record.get('c') == 'HEADER':
                label += 1
                
            res['text'].append(line)
            res['label'].append(label)
            
    return pd.DataFrame(res)
```

Output:

```
>>> prhases_and_labels(sentences)

                                                                 text  label
0                                           Opus dei, la vie en rose.      1
1                                   Ipsum lorem, Suspendisse posuere.      1
2             Nulla elementum, augue fringilla tincidunt ullamcorper.      1
3      Ut sollicitudin mauris sem, ut ultricies ante accumsan dictum.      1
4                                       NEW Opus dei, la vie en rose.      2
5                               NEW Ipsum lorem, Suspendisse posuere.      2
6         NEW Nulla elementum, augue fringilla tincidunt ullamcorper.      2
7  NEW Ut sollicitudin mauris sem, ut ultricies ante accumsan dictum.      2
```